# Wifi settings do not show up

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

What I face for these few days are:

1. The wireless devices for wifi from PC settings does not show up.
2. When I press the fn & signal symbol at the keyboard, it always shows my airplane mode on and off. It's unable for wifi.
3. From the right side screen, at the above, I can see clearly the wifi bar is full (connected with the broadband). But when I click to it, it is not responding.
4. I swept the right side of the screen to check on the setting, It still the same. I can see clearly the wifi bar is filled, but when I click it, it's not responding.

Please help me how to solve it. It's hard for me as I'm a student who uses the computer and internet everyday.

Comment: Are you saying the Wifi on your laptop never works? Or sometimes doesn't work? Did it ever work? We only know what you tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Network Troubleshooter. You can find [instructions at Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-network-adapter-problems#1TC=windows-8). If that fails, try restoring your PC to a date before you started having WiFi problems. If that fails try a refresh. Instructions for both of these can be found [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc?src=ia&iaaid=50004900&ialnk=title):